# Search using VBscript and populate Options dynamically

Tags: search, vbscript, html-select, hta

**Objective**

To search through a bunch of lines in a text file, and if a match is found populate that line in a Options list that is displayed in HTA.
Eg: If 'Setup' is found in 5 lines out of total 10, all the 5 lines need to be populated as 'Options'

**Code**

```
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
Set objRegEx = New RegExp
        With objRegEx

        .Pattern    = "(\b" & "setup" & "\b)"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global     = True
        End With

Set objOpen = objFSO.OpenTextFile ("FileList.lst", 1)
Contents = objOpen.ReadAll


Set objMatchAll = objRegEx.Execute( Contents )
If objMatchAll.count > 0 Then

    Set objOpen = objFSO.OpenTextFile ("FileList.lst", 1)
        Do Until objOpen.AtEndOfStream
            Line = objOpen.ReadLine
            Set objMatchAny = objRegEx.Execute( Line )
                        If objMatchAny.count > 0 Then
                            Set objOption = Document.createElement("OPTION")
                            objOption.Text = Line
                            objOption.Value = Line
                            ValuesList.add objOption
                            'Matched = Matched & vbNewLine & Line
                            MatchCount = MatchCount + 1

                        End If
        Loop
Else                                

    MsgBox "No results"
End If
```

**Explanation**

The code looks for the term 'setup' (of course this is dynamically populated at the time of execution) in the file 'FileList.lst'. When results are found an 'Option' object is generated and added to the 'ValuesList' List which is in an HTML body using  tags.

Note 1: The reason i generate an 'Options' object instead of just loading the line is so that we can populate the  tag. The  tag is used so we can select any one of the search result.

Note 2: The reason the 'Contents' variable is created so that incase if there are no matches at all, it need not go to each line to find a match, which would take longer to just display that message.

**Problem**

The code works fine, tested upto 150 results (outcome), but when there is a large number of matches my HTA freezes.

**Question**

1. Can the existing code be modified to perform better, like a different method to instead of creating the an 'Options' object, an alternate method to generate the 'ValuesList' ?
2. Instead of running two objRegEx search results, is there way to return the matched line from 'Contents' Varialable ?

**Update**

Ok, i ran my script without the objOption part which is not creating and adding options to my ValuesList, only regexp parsing through 58k lines, also resulting in 58k matches and the outcome was 3secs ... so looks like i need an alternative to populate my HTA options list ... its not able to handle that many options to select from ... any alternatives ? I used the same logic in a browser and the entire browser freezes ...

Comment: What's the point of the first regex? It seems like an attempt at optimization, but I don't really see the benefit. If you just want the "No results" MsgBox, you can check the `MatchCount` variable after the loop.

Comment: Please refer Note 2 , i do that so if there are no matches at all then then the code need not go into individual lines to print out the match

Comment: Which one would you consider ? Load all 1000 lines into a variable and parse them to see if there is 'first' match or go through each of the lines and then see if there is a match in the line ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Cheran Shunmugavel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249624/cheran-shunmugavel) i found out that the best way is to use DocumentFragments. I impleted that concept in my code and the results were great !

**New Code**

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
Set objRegEx = New RegExp
        With objRegEx

        .Pattern    = "(\b" & "setup" & "\b)"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global     = True
        End With

Set objFragment = Document.createDocumentFragment()
Set objOpen = objFSO.OpenTextFile ("FileList.lst", 1)
Contents = objOpen.ReadAll


Set objMatchAll = objRegEx.Execute( Contents )
If objMatchAll.count > 0 Then

    Set objOpen = objFSO.OpenTextFile ("FileList.lst", 1)
        Do Until objOpen.AtEndOfStream
            Line = objOpen.ReadLine
            Set objMatchAny = objRegEx.Execute( Line )
                        If objMatchAny.count > 0 Then
                            Set objOption = Document.createElement("OPTION")
                            objOption.innerHTML = Line
                objFragment.appendchild objOption
                            MatchCount = MatchCount + 1

                        End If
        Loop

    ViewList.appendChild objFragment.cloneNode(True)
Else                                

    MsgBox "No results"
End If
```

Old Code : 53mins 23secs

New Code : 31secs

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you really only care about whether or not the regex matches in a particular line or not. Since you don't need to know how many matches occurred, nor do you need the actual match text, you can use the [`Test`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y32x2hy1%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method instead. This should be faster because it will stop after the first match, plus it doesn't have to construct the `Matches` collection. I'd also leave the `Global` property at its default value of `False` for pretty much the same reason, but if you're just using the `Test` method, I don't think the `Global` property matters.

Comment: Interesting ... but i think the HTA hangs due to Option generation and not really the matches ... i shall try your suggestion and see if there is any improvement ....

Comment: Ok, i ran my script without the objOption part, only regexp parsing through 58k lines, also resulting in 58k matches and the outcome was 3secs ... so looks like i need an alternative to populate my HTA options list ... its not able to handle that many options to select from ...

Comment: One possible option: http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/ ... basically you're looking for efficient DOM manipulation techniques. I'd bet 99.5% of the posts out there for DOM manipulation are about using JavaScript, but you should be able to translate some of them to VBScript.